# Why is the on change function not working for my range slider when using arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard, slider, onchange

I'm having an issue with my range slider in html and javascript

```
<input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider" value="60" min="0"   max="100">
```

It displays correctly, moves with arrow keys after I click on it and when I drag the slider. The problem is the function doesn't fire when I use the arrow keys, only when I drag the slider with the mouse:

```
$('#slider').on('change',function() {
var x = $(this).val();
   document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = x + "px";
    document.getElementById('button').style.fontSize = x + "px";
console.log(x);});
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LbLw81oa/1/

I've also been looking around the internet, but haven't found anything on the topic. The only similar thing I found was this website: http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/, but the version of jquery they use breaks a lot of functions in my otherwise working code.
Thanks for your time, any input would help.

Comment: Your never specify for it to do anything on a `onKeyDown` or release or hold, etc.

Comment: Since it slides with the arrow keys hasn't it changed the value?

Comment: It doesn't slide with the arrow keys by default so nothing is changed when they are pressed.

Comment: Hm, do you know why it is sliding when I use the arrow keys after I've clicked on it? I have noticed that usually you have to change the setting in order for it to do so, but like I said after I click on it or it is focused it does move when I use the arrow keys.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't mention that it is moveable with the arrow keys *after I click on it. Just made that edit

Comment: It does that because it's HTML and most browsers have those actions built in. If you want it to change every time it's changed, you'd need to execute something on a setInterval.

Comment: Never mind, read the question wrong, I don't know why it isn't working, maybe `'change'` isn't a valid jQuery type?

Comment: Thanks, just found another method to write the function as
    .change(function() 
and its still working for dragging with the mouse, but the arrows are still bringing up the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle you had an extra .style on line 3 of you fiddle. Then the keys fire function (tested in Chrome) once .style removed.

```
 document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = x + "px";
```

[Updated Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LbLw81oa/2/)

Comment: Just came back to work and noticed it's still not working in firefox, must be something weird with the browser that I'm going to have to look into. Thanks again though

Comment: The change event in FF only fires on mouse-up. Input event resolves it. Input not supported in IE10 so you need both input and change. http://jsfiddle.net/LbLw81oa/3/

Comment: I found the input action a few months ago. It's a life saver for mobile too. Glad I could help.

Comment: It works on both IE10 and FF11. for changing font size you need to add `px`. [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbLw81oa/14/)